# Created .Net Core 3.1 Project, but nothing loads

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

I have created a .Net Core (MVC) 3.1 solution, but none of the pages load.

Comes up with "This localhost page can’t be found".

Is anyone able to assist? Feel free to ask questions also.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,you need to make sure routing is registered in Startup.Configure:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            ...

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
```

And then you need to make sure if the razor view exists and action exists.For example:
[image]

HomeController:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        ...

        public IActionResult Test()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

result(You also need to check if the url is right):
[image]